# Where and how the iBooks page flipping effects is programmed?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, html, epub

As far as I can read, ibooks format is similar to epub format http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/apple-events/thoughts-on-ibooks-author, a bunch of html/js files. 
But where/how the page flipping is programmed ?

I have downloaded iBooks Author on my mac http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/ibooks-author/id490152466?mt=12 , when testing on iPad iBooks 2, I can't get this flipping page effect whereas when I download iBooks from official library it has that page flipping effect.

So could I modify the html/js generated by iBooks Author by hand to get that effect ? If yes how because I can't find any documentation searching the Internet.

Comment: Good question. Basically, it boils down to "why has Apple not included this as an option in iBooks Author and how to remedy it?"

Comment: yes that's my question why on earth :)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of HTML5 "page flip" tutorials - a few of my favorite ones are on HTML5rocks.com...

Check out this case study:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip.html

Comment: Thanks quite nice :) but specifically for ibooks it isn't exactly same effect and it seems all books have the same flipping effect so I thought it was somehow a standard of ibooks.

Comment: @Michael Manoochehri That's "how to emulate the effect". I think user310291 was more "how to call Apple's page turning effect when using the Apple generation tool instead of another environment, like Vi/emacs".

Answer (score 1):

There is one that is automatically created for you as an xcode Project type its called the  `paged based application`! Hope that helps!